# How to use Aws code-deploy with Auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

We have auto-scaling group behind an Application load balancer which launches instances if the avg. CPU Utilization goes beyond 70%.

We have created a base AMI for the auto-scaling group.

But the problem is that our website updates almost on a regular or weekly basis so what we can configure to allow AWS code-deploy to automatically deploy our latest revision from github on those instances created via auto-scaling group?

If any more information is required please let me know.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate which aspect specifically you are struggling with? Have you read this for example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-auto-scaling-group.html

Comment: According to docs, what I understood is that I just have to point the deployment group to Auto-scaling group. Is that it? How will the code-deploy know which revision or commit to deploy on the auto-scaling instances?

Comment: For that you should use CodePipeline to trigger the CodeDeploy if you want it automated.

Comment: Check out this article: https://medium.com/@ariklevliber/continuous-deployment-with-aws-codepipeline-codedeploy-and-github-on-ec2-36eeccfb7a5e

Comment: Nice! I didn't indulge in Codepipeline because I didn't want to complicate things too much and I was manually deploying the latest commit by going to code-deploy in the console or via aws CLI and using the latest githun commit ID for deployment. Codepipeline looks better.

Comment: I'm new to aws environment. It's been a week only that I've started using AWS so things get confusing for me pretty easily.

Comment: Easy to do, they have a crazy number of services.

Comment: Is there a way that I can directly connect to you for any help? Discord or anything? If that's okay with you.

Comment: You can reach me here: https://uk.linkedin.com/in/alexjmoore

Comment: Thank you! One thing more, when I'm manually deploying my code via aws code-deploy console using the latest github commit id, code deployment process is getting stuck at "allow traffic" step. Do you have any idea, why? I searched about this on google but didn't found anything to solve the problem.

Comment: 1) you don't need Pipelines, 2) to avoid getting stuck at "allow traffic", set your `Deployment type` to `In-place`

Answer (score 0):

Code Deploy fully supports Auto Scaling.

Here are the steps to integrate these two services: **[Integrating CodeDeploy with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html)**

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to point the deployment group to Auto-scaling group.

It is a horrifying implicit magic.

However, to make it work you need to set `Deployment type In-place`, or you will get a new auto scaling group instead. And it mean that you still need 2 instances at least.

`Initiating event` on each 'Deployment' can tell you more. If your autoScaling group would start a new instance, you will have a new deployment in your `CodeDeploy` and the `Initiating event` would say `autoScaling`, when normally it would say `user`.

Also look into `Auto Scaling Group Lifecycle Hook`. The `Code deploy` creates the hook and name it like so

```
CodeDeploy-managed-automatic-launch-deployment-hook-Your-Deployment-Group-name-some_numbers
```

and it somehow knows the `Revision`. [Documentetion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#preparing-for-notification).

I could not trace of how `SQS Notification` from `Auto Scaling Group Lifecycle Hook` connected to exact `CodeDeploy Deployment group` and that is why I call it `magic`.